# Get n number of emails from IMAP irrespective of the date

Tags: ruby, imap

At the moment I am importing emails like this:

```
google.email.all folder: folder, keys: [ 'SINCE', since_time ] do |mail, imap, uid|
  flags = imap.uid_fetch(uid, ['FLAGS'])[0].attr['FLAGS']
```

The client wants to be able to pull 'n' number of emails from the selected folder irrespective of when the date is.

Can I query in anything other than 'SINCE' to acheieve the result without just pulling in everything?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it works in Ruby, but in IMAP you just do:

01 FETCH 1:20 (UID FLAGS)

Where 20 is your 'n', replace as needed. You can see an example in [this article](http://www.programmersranch.com/2013/08/imap-message-and-folder-attributes.html) of mine.